# Files/Media folders owned by an app on Extremal Storage on microSD card: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-mediarecorder, android-external-storage, android-storage

I have an app which records videos. It has an option to record videos to external microSD card.

Some users of my app reports the next issue:

> MediaRecorder init error
> /storage/7491-17FD/Android/media/MY_APP_PACKAGE/2020-12-25/2020-12-25
> 15h 00m 16s.mp4: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system).

I tested my real devices Samsung S10 (Android 29) and Lenovo P1ma40 (Android 21) with external microSD card. Everything works fine. Also tested with Pixels emulators. App can record video files (and creating other files) to such folders and they can be deleted without any problem within that app. So there is no need for any permissions, it should have R/W rights by default (because it is folders of that app).

So why does such issue happen for other users (their devices)?

Comment: Android version of those devices?

Comment: `Also tested with Pixels emulators.` Which pixel device can have a removable micro sd card inserted?

Comment: Which function do you use to get a path to that folder?

Comment: `Context.externalMediaDirs`. There is SD Card option in Advanced Settings of an emulator (AVD), of course it's an emulated SD Card but still it has the same limitations due to API. For this issue in the question - Samsung SM-A605FN, Android 10. Also: - Samsung SM-A700F, Android 6.0.1, Blackview A60Pro, Android 9, LeTV Max3-65, Android 8.1 but for those devices issue a little bit different "open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)."

Comment: Check first with File:exists() and File:canWrite() if the mediadir is suitable for your purpose. You can try to create the dir if it does not exist.

Comment: @blackapps I thought those folders owned by app should be always available and writeable (at least it works fine with microSD on my own devices), that's why I didn't add such conditions. But it seems there are always can be issues with some other devices. Though it still should add such conditions to check if card wasn't removed. Though in for reporting by email I also add free space of that path storage in extra text (email intent) and it was 10 GB for that user, so the card wasn't removed

Comment: I have never seen an .../Android/media dir on any device and certainly not ..../Android/media/<packagename>

Comment: @blackapps of course we should create them using `mkdirs()`, it's the same as `Context.getExternalFilesDirs`, the difference is that `Context.externalMediaDirs` allows to scan for media files (Media Scanner) to MediaStore database. Good for video recording apps if user doesn't want to record to shared DCIM or Movies folder, also big plus for microSD card, because you can't easily record on shared/public folders of such storage. Minus that those folders are deleted if app is deleted